# How to define the second DataCenter in Azure Blob Storage ZRS?

Tags: azure, redundancy

I have round about 100 files with 500 MB to 5 GB. These files should be stored in an Azure Blob. Access will happen from Germany (so one DC is Western Europe) and from Asia (so the second DC should be one of the asian DC's).
As far as i understand ZRS is here the way to go.
I already created the blockblob as ZRS in Western Europe but it seems that i cannot find the option to define the second DC for redundancy. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best regards
Axel

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that with Azure Storage. It does that for you automatically. And data won't leave the region in most cases with ZRS (in your it wouldn't). It a case of GRS the replication partner is predefined. Take a look at that article.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-redundancy/

> Zone-redundant storage (ZRS) replicates your data asynchronously across datacenters within one or two regions in addition to storing three replicas similar to LRS

It will use two regions if only a single facility exists in a region.

Also if you want to read the data from the second location you would need RA-GRS, not ZRS

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Do i understand right that Azure Storage does not allow to synchronize storage blobs between DataCenters in different Regions? So there is no way to establish a high performance replicated blob?

Comment: No, it allows for that, but you cannot choose a region. So Geo-Replicated - means replication between regions, but you cannot write to the replica, only read (it its RA-GRS); if its GRS you cannot read from the replica, until a failover occurs.